# Outgoing proxy connection problem

Tags: authentication, proxy

I'm trying to set up Wordpress on a server that requires a proxy connection to connect to the internet. Here's what I put in wp-config.php:

```
/* Configure HTTP Proxy Server */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'xx.xx.xx.xx');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '8080');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', 'xxxxx');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', 'xxxxx');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost');
```

(I replaced real IP, username and password with xxx here for privacy reasons)

Unfortunately, Wordpress still can't connect to the internet. The Site Health page displays this error:

```
Your site is unable to reach WordPress.org at 198.143.164.251, and returned the error: cURL error 56: Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT
```

407 is a Proxy Authentication Required error.

I checked the proxy's IP, username and password many times, and it's definitely correct. The same settings work when I use

```
export http_proxy="http://xxxxx:xxxxx@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080"
```

in the command line, and then download something using wget. It connects via proxy, and downloads the file correctly.

I tried using a packet capture program to see what the connection between Wordpress and the proxy looks like, and the headers look like this:

```
CONNECT api.wordpress.org:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.wordpress.org:443
User-Agent: WordPress/5.2.4; http://xx.xx.xx.xx/
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: close
```

The reply from the proxy server is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 authenticationrequired
Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 11:31:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 4365
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Authenticate: Negotiate
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="McAfee Web Gateway"
```

I think that there should have been a

```
Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

header in the first packet, but for some reason there isn't anything like it. What should I do? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but you can try..

So WordPress' default HTTP transport is using cURL, and the HTTP [class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_curl/) sets the proxy authorization method to `CURLAUTH_ANY` (see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-http-curl.php#L107)), which might explain why the `Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxx...` header is missing from the *request*.

And there's a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_api_curl/) you can try to change the proxy authorization method to `CURLAUTH_BASIC` (which is widely supported, but also very insecure), `CURLAUTH_NTLM` or one of the other available [methods](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html).

So add this to your theme `functions.php` file.. (or put the code into a [Must-Use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)):

```php
add_action( 'http_api_curl', function ( $handle, $r, $url ) {
    $proxy = new WP_HTTP_Proxy();
    if ( $proxy->is_enabled() && $proxy->send_through_proxy( $url ) ) {
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

#### Alternatively, you can set PHP Streams as the default HTTP transport...

```php
add_filter( 'http_api_transports', function ( $transports ) {
    return [ 'streams', 'curl' ];
} );
```

See the hook's [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_api_transports/) and [`WP_Http_Streams`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http_streams/) for more information. But basically, the hook allows you to use a custom class, and `WP_Http_Streams` would always set the `Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxx...` header when necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This helped :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions were working for me. I ended up setting the environment variable that is respected by curl in the terminal, but it only worked directly in the PHP code;

wp-config.php:

```
putenv('https_proxy=socks5://xxxxxx:xxx');
```